# Selenium webdriver: Click not working in python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click first on the link of the table with text `A218012216`.
It seems that table/links code are hidden inside JS.
I tried several ways, but without success.

This is my code so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
url0 ="https://ccrecordse.tarrantcounty.com/AssumedNames/SearchEntry.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Python\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url0)
time.sleep(3)
#fill the form # select by visible text
selectStart = driver.find_element_by_id('x:11265151.0:mkr:3')
selectStart.send_keys('09/05/2019')
selectEnd = driver.find_element_by_id('x:1246303050.0:mkr:3')
selectEnd.send_keys('09/05/2019')
#submit the form
driver.find_element_by_id("cphNoMargin_SearchButtons2_btnSearch__5").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('A218012216').click()
```

How can I get that information?

Comment: Share html or url

Comment: You need to share the HTML source code to get valuable answers.

Comment: URL is inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `find_element_by_link_text` on an element that is not an `<a>` tag link_text is only for `<a>` tags...

In my solution, you will see I am using `WebDriverWait` this is best practice in selenium...

Also, I used the XPath locator with `text()=the_text` note that the `the_text` will need to change as the date changes (you are searching for the future date `09/05/2019` so it shows the current date therefor the text will change...)

**The Solution:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url0 ="https://ccrecordse.tarrantcounty.com/AssumedNames/SearchEntry.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Python\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url0)
time.sleep(3)
#fill the form # select by visible text
selectStart = driver.find_element_by_id('x:11265151.0:mkr:3')
selectStart.send_keys('02/19/2019')
selectEnd = driver.find_element_by_id('x:1246303050.0:mkr:3')
selectEnd.send_keys('02/19/2019')
#submit the form
driver.find_element_by_id("cphNoMargin_SearchButtons2_btnSearch__5").click()
the_text = "A219002410"
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='"+the_text +"']"))).click()
```

Hope this helps you!